# iOS Swift UIImageView with aspect ratio not getting hide

Tags: ios, swift, aspect-ratio

In my application I want to show customise buttons like:

- Title Only Button
- Button with Image + Title
- Image Only Button

[image] 
[image] 
[image]

To create a such button I have taken a `UIView` and Under That I have added `UIImageView` with `aspect ratio` of 24:48 and `UILable`.

For button Type Image + Title everything works fine but for Title only button my `UIIlmageView` is not getting hidden i.e. even I have added

```
        leftImageviewWidthConstaraint.constant = 0

        leftImageviewWidthConstaraint.isActive = false
```

what else I am missing. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `leftImageviewWidthConstaraint.isActive = false` you turn off the constraint, so natural content size might cause it to still be visible..

So just do

`leftImageviewWidthConstaraint.constant = 0` to change the value and DONT disable it after.

You can also try a `self.layoutIfNeeded()` after adjusting constraints; on rare occasions that helps

Comment: Ok, let me try.

Comment: where do you define your `leftImageviewWidthConstaraint`

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is add the UIImageView and the UILabel in a horizontal UIStackView with Fill Proportionally distribution. This way if you give the UIImageView a fixed size, the UILabel will get the rest of the space and if you HIDE the UIImageView, the UILabel will get the whole space of the StackView. Same thing if you hide the UILabel.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Can i give UIImageView size as 24:48 inside of UIStackView as, this is the requirement that, image should be 24 * 24

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the *leading* or *left* constraint of the label is connected to the *trailing* or *right* constraint of the image view and not to the left side of the container view. By calling `leftImageviewWidthConstaraint.constant = 0` it should work. And don't deactivate the constraint, you might have crashes or other UI issues. I just gave it a try and it works for me:

[image]